# plumber @post results in "404 - Resource Not Found"

Tags: r, post, plumber

I tried replicating part of the example on this [page](http://plumber.trestletech.com/docs/endpoints/).  However, when I try the `http://my-host:8000/input?val=1` it gives me the error `{"error":["404 - Resource Not Found"]}`

Am I missing anything?

**plumb-test.R**

```
mylist <- 15

#* @post /input
function(val, res){
  v <- as.numeric(val)
  if (is.na(v)){
    res$status <- 400
    res$body <- "val parameter must be a number"
    return(res)
  }
  mylist <<- c(mylist,val)

  list(result="success")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using curl with -X POST like this:

```
curl -X POST "http://my-host:8000/input?val=1"
```